# Reinstalling Apache Tomcat7 on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu

I had installed tomcat7 on ubuntu and then I deleted the /etc/tomcat7 folder to completely remove it. Now I want to reinstall Tomcat7, but the sudo apt-get install tomcat7 command gives me error. Can someone help me out with this issue?

Error --
[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I found out the problem. I am posting this for future reference.

This problem can be solved by using the command --

```
 sudo apt-get purge tomcat7
```

This removes all the related dependencies. After this I did --

```
 sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```